# How to get Json data in web service without xml and string?

Tags: c#, json, xml, web-services

I'm using Angularjs so need to get the output data in json format. I have tried the Web service as given below for getting the data from database. In this wen service I'm getting output with xml and string. I need without xml and string.

Here is the code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetDateTimeFormats()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string strQuery = null;
        strQuery = "sql query";
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["constr"];
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row = default(Dictionary<string, object>);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Newtonsoft.Json package. And try this code.

Code

```
public class HelloWorldData
    {
        public String Message;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void getEmployee()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        HelloWorldData data = new HelloWorldData();
        string sql = "SQL_QUERTY";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONNECTION_STRING"]);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
    }
```